# Differences between SeriesCollection and FullSeriesCollection

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clean some auto generated code and I am rather new with the series functionality in excel. So in many websites/forums I found people using a lot more `SeriesCollection` instead of my generated code using `FullSeriesCollection`.

My code is filtering some stuff and then it is setting the x axis values of a chart so it is doing that:

`.ChartObjects("Voltage").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Parametric_Sheet!D:D"`

I'm trying to know if this code is ok or not or if I can clean it.

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.fullseriescollection) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure someone else will give more info.

At least one difference is seriesCollection is backwards compatible across Excel version.

Your code is fine for newer Excel versions but if you want to ensure compatibility across then use seriesCollection instead.

Comment: `FullSeriesCollection` includes `Series` objects that may be filtered out.

Comment: @BigBen Ok got it, so `FullSeriesCollection` has been generated because I was filtering some data just before that line of code. thx!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the document definaion from MS, I'm also confused with them, hope those info helps.

[SeriesCollection object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.seriescollection)

> A collection of all the Series objects in the specified chart or chart
> group.

[FullSeriesCollection object (Excel):](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.fullseriescollection)

> Represents the full set of Series objects in a chart.
> The FullSeriesCollection object enables you to get a filtered out
> Series object and filter it back in. It also enables you to iterate
> over the full set of Series objects, filtered out or visible,
> programmatically.
>
> By having the existing SeriesCollection object contain only the
> visible series, you can programmatically perform operations on only
> the visible series. It also prevents Microsoft Excel from breaking
> existing chart solutions on charts with filtered out data.

I have changed the chart series.format.line.weitht, it work with

```
mychart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.Weight = 0.5
```

but not with this:

```
mychart.Chart.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.Weight = 0.5
```

[Series.Format property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.series.format)

Returns the ChartFormat object. Read-only.