# VBA - .DataLabels.NumberFormat - "Object doesn't support this property or method" error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I try to change number format of my data labels, but there is an error (on bold line)? Do You have any idea what`s wrong?

```
Range("R1:S" & NRegion).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(494, xlRegionMap).Name = "Wykres 2"

Set wykres2 = Sheets("Raport").ChartObjects("Wykres 2").Chart

    Sheets("Raport").ChartObjects("Wykres 2").Activate
    ActiveChart.Legend.Position = xlBottom
    ActiveChart.Legend.Format.Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Wartość zamówień w województwach"
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
    wykres2.FullSeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    **wykres2.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.NumberFormat = "# ##0 zł"**
    wykres2.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = " "
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56363515/differences-between-seriescollection-and-fullseriescollection

Comment: I used SeriesCollection(1) instead of FullSeriesCollection(1), but it still doesn`t work

Comment: Does your chart already have some values added to it? If the chart is empty, VBA won't be able to change the Data Labels etc.

Comment: Yes, the values are added to it

Comment: How about using `ActiveChart` instead of referring to `wykres2`? So it would be: `ActiveChar.FullSeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels`. By the way, what is the error message that gets displayed on this line?